# What is wrong with the syntax on this case statement?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am trying to insert values into a temp table via a cursor and if they have a period on the end, I would like to remove the period. Here is the code I am having syntax issues with.

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    CASE SELECT CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@Category))  
        WHEN 1
        THEN INSERT INTO #Category VALUES (SUBSTRING(@Category,1,LEN(@Category)-1)))
END;
```

What am I doing incorrectly here? I'm open to more efficient answers but would also like to know how to solve it this way.

Comment: `CASE` is an **expression** not a statement; that may be all the help you need...

Comment: Use `if` instead of `case`.  However, there is a good chance you do not need a cursor at all for what you are doing.

Comment: @AakashM, this is actually the case statement. (Case expression has a return value, but this is just conditional execution.) Perhaps not supported by SQL Server, but defined by ANSI/ISO SQL.

Comment: Why are you using a cursor to do inserts like this in the first place? You could probably rewrite your entire insert as a single insert statement.

Answer (score 3):

[CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx) yields an expression, not a statement. You are looking for the [IF statement](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182717(v=sql.120).aspx).

As for a better way to do this: Scrap the cursor and use an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... WHERE CHARINDEX('.', REVERSE(category)) = 1` statement.

Comment: I'm just learning about cursors which is why I'm implementing one on this problem. No doubt that the set based solution would be quicker, but thank you for the quick response!

Answer (score 3):

`CASE` is used to compute an expression, not control program flow.  Use `IF` instead:

```
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    IF CHARINDEX('.',REVERSE(@Category)) = 1
        INSERT INTO #Category VALUES (SUBSTRING(@Category,1,LEN(@Category)-1)))
END;
```

Although if `@Category` is computed from an expression off of your cursor then you may see significant improvement by using an `INSERT INTO` instead of looping and executing individual `INSERT` statements.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Thank you.